# Regex number OR a symbol

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex that will meet the following requirements for a password.

1. Must have at least 1 uppercase
2. Must have at least 1 lowercase
3. Must contain a number OR a symbol - FAILS
4. Must be between 8 to 16 characters long

   `^(?=.*\d|[!@#\$%\^&])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,16}$`

I've got it working, well almost, except the OR part. 
It verifies for instance Tester01 and Tester0% but it wont verify Tester%$ or anything with two symbols, just in case the user doesn't put in a number. I've also tried putting brackets around the \d thinking I had to separate the digits from the symbols but that didn't work.

Comment: What is your language 'flavor'? PowerShell?

Comment: You missed `.*` before your special character class or you can add `\d` itself in character class

Comment: You might find [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48345922/3600709) useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your alternation condition isn't correct. Instead you can just slide the `\d` within the special characters bracket and change your regex to this,

```
^(?=.*[\d!@#\$%\^&])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,16}$
```

Now your this look ahead `(?=.*[\d!@#\$%\^&])` behaves exactly as you wanted. It will ensure that either one character is any digit or the other special characters mentioned in your character class.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZlYuoY/1)**

The reason why your look ahead `(?=.*\d|[!@#\$%\^&])` fails is because your first alternation condition is `.*\d` and second is merely `[!@#\$%\^&]` where as if correctly written it should have been either this,

```
(?=.*\d|.*[!@#\$%\^&])
```

OR

```
(?=.*(\d|[!@#\$%\^&]))
```

And you really don't need alternation at all if you write it like the way I have written above, where you can just put `\d` within the character set itself, like this,

```
(?=.*([\d!@#\$%\^&]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the principle of contrast with multiple lookaheads.

```
^
(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])
(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])
(?=[^\d!@#\$%\^&]*[^\d!@#\$%\^&])
.{8,16}
$
```

But [**please read this post as well**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation/48346033#48346033) (why password validations are bad?) and see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/zoZZuE/1).

Comment: Ah yes, thank you. A bit of an eye opener for passwords rules

Comment: @JK36: That's why I linked it here. It pops up quite often on SO, admittedly.